# How do I programmatically get the content title field from a view?

Tags: views, 8, hooks

How do I programmatically get the content title field from a view?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this out:
The following example with hook [hook_preprocess_views_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view/8.2.x)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_views_view().
 */
function myModule_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];
  $result = $view->result;
  //- Titles Array 
  $titles = [];
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
    $titles[]= $result[$i]->_entity->title->value;
  }
}
```

Comment: you are welcome, glad that help.